# How to convert ASCII values to RGB values in Java?

Tags: java, image

I am trying to convert a text file into an image. I tried to read the file and convert the ASCII values of the characters into RGB values. But the result image is just a blank image. Can anyone help me with this? Here is a part of my code.

```
for(int i=0;i<=img.getHeight();i++)
    {
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
        for(int j=0;j<line.length();j++)
        {
            int color=(int)line.charAt(j);
            img.setRGB(j,i,color);
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "ASCII values"? Are you trying to convert ASCII art or does the text file have the actual RGB values written in ASCII? Can u post an example?

Comment: How have you encoded RGB values as characters in the text file?

Comment: It is a normal .txt file. I am trying to read it char by char, convert that char to int and add it to an image.

Comment: maybe this [link](https://github.com/B0nde/From-ASCII-to-RGB-Grayscale-image-converter/blob/master/src/b0nde/asciiconverter/Main.java) can help. 
`int value = ((int)asciiLine.charAt(x));
int r = value << 16;
int b = value << 8;
int g = value;`

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about a PPM image in ASCII format? It would certainly help people understand what you are trying to achieve, if you could post a sample of your input data.

Comment: @TejaswiRamanujan that doesn't answer our questions about the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

java color has build in support

```
Color.decode(hexString)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `char` values you get from an ASCII text will be in the range [0...255] (8 bit values). `BufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, color)` expects `color` to be a full 32 bit ARGB value. Because all 8 high bits of your pixels will be 0, the colors are interpreted as fully transparent, that is why you see a blank picture.

*For the rest of the answer, I'm assuming that you actually have pixels stored like this, though it's not very common. If you had shown the input data, I could have verified.*

Depending on what your input ASCII data contains (RGB? ARGB? gray data?), you need to pack the values to represent the full ARGB value:

For gray:

```
int gray = line.charAt(j) & 0xff;
int ARGB = 0xff000000 | gray << 16 | gray << 8 | gray;
```

For RGB (you need to increment `j` in steps of three (`j += 3`)):

```
int red = line.charAt(j) & 0xff;
int green = line.charAt(j + 1) & 0xff;
int blue = line.charAt(j + 2) & 0xff;
int ARGB = 0xff000000 | red << 16 | green << 8 | blue:
```

For ARGB (you need to increment `j` in steps of four (`j += 4`)):

```
int alpha = line.charAt(j) & 0xff;
int red = line.charAt(j + 1) & 0xff;
int green = line.charAt(j + 2) & 0xff;
int blue = line.charAt(j + 3) & 0xff;
int ARGB = alpha << 24 | red << 16 | green << 8 | blue:
```